# Ubuntu will not connect to existing ad-hoc network?

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager, raspberrypi

I set up a broadcasting ad-hoc network on my Raspberry Pi 3, I want to connect to it from my ubuntu host.

The connection appears in my network manager but I cannot connect to the network.

The Raspberry Pi ad-hoc network connects two raspberry Pi's together beautifully.

On each of the Rpi's

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1  ##(192.168.1.2 on the other Rpi)##
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-channel 7
    wireless-essid mazuNet
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

On Ubuntu machine (I'm not allowed to embed images yet):

[available networks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpQnK.png)

[connection info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEDZk.png)

[more connection info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOPve.png)

Am I defining my static IP incorrectly?

I tried editing my `/etc/network/interfaces` on my Ubuntu machine to no avail.

Thank you, any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After editing my Ubuntu's interfaces file.

I believe I had set the wrong "wireless-channel" on my host machine originally.

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.3
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-channel 7
    wireless-essid mazuNet
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

login with: `ssh pi@192.168.1.1` or `ssh pi@192.168.1.2` (to the other Pi)

Is there a better way to set this connection up to make switching between my ad-hoc network and regular wifi connections more quickly?

Currently I have to manually edit my interfaces file then reboot.